# In Corda 3, using Cash with a mock network throws the following error: Please register the entity <ENTITY_NAME>

Tags: corda

I am trying to run the Obligation CorDapp [here](https://github.com/corda/samples) on Corda 3. I am getting following error when issuing cash:

```
Cannot find contract attachments for [net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash]. See https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging
```

And when settling I get this:

```
Please register the entity ‘net.corda.finance.schemas.CashSchemaV1’ See https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#custom-schema-registration for more information
```

I have tried following solutions:

- [Error While Fetching Data from Corda Custom Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175392/error-while-fetching-data-from-corda-custom-tables)
- https://docs.corda.net/api-contract-constraints.html#debugging

But nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register both packages with the `MockNetwork`, as follows:

```
network = MockNetwork(
    listOf("net.corda.finance.contracts.asset", "net.corda.finance.schemas")
)
```