# Please register the entity 'net.corda.finance.schemas.CashSchemaV1'

Tags: corda

[In Corda 3, using Cash with a mock network throws the following error: Please register the entity <ENTITY_NAME>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428000/in-corda-3-using-cash-with-a-mock-network-throws-the-following-error-please-re?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Am getting an error while accessing the cash-balance api in Obligation cordapp-newrelease-NEW. Which file have to edit inorder to overcome error shown below.

Please register the entity 'net.corda.finance.schemas.CashSchemaV1'
See https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#custom-schema-registration for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the `corda-finance` module/CorDapp to you node. If you are using deploy nodes use something like the code below

```
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        cordapps = [
                "$project.group:cordapp-contracts-states:$project.version",
                "$project.group:cordapp:$project.version",
                "$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Am running through Intellij

Comment: So how are you running it? As far as I am aware that is not possible by itself. What are you doing to deploy the nodes?

Comment: If you are using the node driver, you need to add the `finance` package to the list of packages the driver scans, as follows: `driver(DriverParameters(extraCordappPackagesToScan = listOf("net.corda.finance.contracts.asset", "net.corda.finance.schemas")), dsl = { ... })`

Comment: I have used NodeDriverKt File to add nodes and all.